# jQuery-UI DatePicker not working with Aurelia and Typescript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to create a wrapper (custom attribute) around jQuery UI DatePicker. The **`date-picker.ts`** looks like below so far:

```
import {inject, bindable} from "aurelia-framework";

export class DatePickerCustomAttribute {
   static inject = [Element];

   @bindable isdate;

   constructor(public element:Element) {
   }

   bind() {
       if (this.isdate) {
           console.log("trying to set datepicker");
           $(this.element).datepicker();
       }
   }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
<require from="./date-picker"></require>
...
<input ... date-picker="isdate.bind:isDate"/>
```

This works in Chrome, however not in Firefox or Edge. The code throws an error on execution of this line: `$(this.element).datepicker();`. And the error says: `Error: Assertion failed`.

My Development Setup: Visual Studio 2015 - Aurelia - Typescript 1.5.4 - along with the necessary type definitions such as for aurelia, jQuery, [jQueryui](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jqueryui), and [jQuery-ui-datetimepicker](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/69303fd9e52d8e0e97a92d096966aea5fb7630c5/jquery.ui.datetimepicker).

Requesting for help and suggestions.

Thank You.

**EDIT:**
The stack trace is something like this:

```
Stack trace: 
assert@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/webcomponents.js:112:21
assertIsNodeWrapper@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/webcomponents.js:1573:7
.insertBefore@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/webcomponents.js:1787:9
.appendChild@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/webcomponents.js:1784:16
.buildFragment@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js:5150:18
.domManip@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js:5387:15
.append@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js:5218:1
$.fn.datepicker@https://localhost:44300/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js:5811:3
DatePickerCustomAttribute</DatePickerCustomAttribute.prototype.bind@https://localhost:44300/aureliaviews/shared/date-picker.js:19:17
.......
```

Comment: what's the stack trace

Comment: Please check my edit. As the stack trace is quite long, I have added a part of it. In case the entire stack trace is required, please let me know.

Comment: I've written a blog that might interest you about integrating third party libraries into Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webcomponents.js (polymer) is causing the issue.  Try removing your dependency on that library.  More troubleshooting tips here:

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/301